# "Illegal Instruction" when running Imagemagick on Raspberrypi (Buster)

Tags: raspberry-pi, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, debian-buster

I have a Pi that's running Raspbian Buster:

```
uname -a
Linux myPi 4.19.97+ #1294 Thu Jan 30 13:10:54 GMT 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I did install Imagemagick:

```
$ sudo apt install imagemagick -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  imagemagick
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 636 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/156 kB of archives.
After this operation, 215 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package imagemagick.
(Reading database ... 62109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../imagemagick_8%3a6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1+deb10u1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking imagemagick (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1+deb10u1) ...
Setting up imagemagick (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1+deb10u1) ...
```

Now when I run `convert` I get a very generic error **Illegal Instruction**:

```
$ convert
Illegal instruction
```

I did check dmesg and `/var/log/syslog` but did not find any references.
So currently I have no clue on how to debug this. I'm running the same script on another Pi without any troubles.

### Update

I just checked the Pi that works:

```
uname -a
Linux myOtherPi 5.10.63+ #1496 Wed Dec 1 15:57:05 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux

convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 arm 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 1):

The RPi 1 model is running on ARMv6, but the installed imagemagick package (imagemagick_xxx_armhf.deb) is for armhf (ARM hard float, supported from ARMv7) platform, that's why your RPi 1 is not able to run the required instructions.

BTW, Your another RPi is probably RPi 2+ version.

### Update

To complement my above answer, we also need to take OS into consideration.

Let's look at 3 involved arm ports, according to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmPorts),

- **Debian ArmEabiPort** supports armv4t+ without hard floating
- **Debian ArmHardFloatPort** supports armv7+ with hard floating
- **Raspbian** will supports armhf packages on both armv6/armv7 with hard floating

Theoretically, RPi1(armv6) can install **Debian ArmEabiPort** or **Raspbian**, and run,

1. armel packages on Debian ArmEabiPort or Raspbian
2. both armel and armhf packages on Raspbian

So, back to your case, here are **2 possibilities**,

1. your faulty RPi is running Debian instead of Raspbian or possiblly [mixed up repositories](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87392/pi1-armv6-how-to-disable-armhf-packages), but trying to install armhf package?
2. your another RPi is running armel version of program?

You could check os version,

```sh
cat /etc/os-release
```

and check apt package version,

```sh
apt-cache policy imagemagick
```

Comment: Well nope, the working one is an armv6 too... It has another kernel version. So updating the kernel is something I might consider.

Comment: Oh, my bad guessing:) Actually there's also a possibility about your OS, could you check on your both RPis for the following commands and share the outputs, 

1) cat /etc/os-release
2) apt-cache policy imagemagick